# Dell Keyboard (KB813) with smart card reader not working

Tags: 20.04, dell, card-reader, smartcard

We have multiple ***Dell Keyboard with smart card readers(Model KB813)***. We have instructed to install ubuntu and check the compatibility with all available hardware devices. Everything works fine but dell keyboards.
Keyboard is working but the inbuilt smart card reader is not working.
we are using ***Ubuntu 20.04 FF on dell 780 PCs***. we also have other models like Optiplex 780,790,7010,3040,3050 etc.
Is there any way to make this thing work?

I have been searching on this thing for days. I have also searched the already posted threads but nothing works.

**What I tried :**
sudo apt-get install libacr38u libacr38ucontrol0 libacr38ucontrol-dev and also
Installed CardPeek.

Comment: *libacr38u* is not available on 20.04. Did you try to install *pcscd, pcsc-tools* and possibly *libccid*. Then, you can run **pcsc_scan** and insert/remove the card to see whether it is detected.